# gatt null via BLE sending command in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Gatt is null when I calling from command sending command via BLE. Can any one help me. where I am getting gatt null

```
public void registrationBLECommand() {
      //  Log.d("jyothi","")
        if (bluetoothGatt != null){
            getRegistartionBLE(bluetoothGatt);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(activity,"gatt null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void getRegistartionBLE(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {
        jsonString = "{\"i\": 1, \"v\": 1, \"t\": 11, \"ts\": 1, \"m\": 1 }";
         writeCommand(bluetoothGatt, jsonString);
    }

    public void writeCommand(BluetoothGatt gatt,String jsonString) {
        if (gatt != null) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = gatt.getServices();
            for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
                String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
                if (serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                            gattCharacteristics) {
                        final String uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                        if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(TX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                            byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes();
                            boolean writeValueStatus = gattCharacteristic.setValue(payload);
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                return;
                            }
                            boolean writeStatus = gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

gatt should not be null ,command is not sending via BLE .try to send getting null in all the time

Comment: You should add all relevant code. You ask us *where I am getting gatt null* but only you can know it because you didn't add the code where you initialize the gatt and where you call `writeCommand` but just orphan functions that we don't know who owns and uses them.